# How to infer return type of Promise based on function arguments?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

```
type Actions =
  | ['add', number, number] // should return number
  | ['log', string]; // should return void


type Call = (...args: Actions) => Promise<?>;

const call: Call = (...args: Actions): Promise<?> => {
  // returns some Promise
}

call('add', 1, 1).then(value => {
   // value is then inferred as number
})


call('log', 'Hello World!').then(value => {
   // value is then inferred as void
})
```

How do you base the return value of the Promise from whatever arguments was passed to the function?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Call` type above?

Comment: why `call('add', 1, 1)` and not just `add(1,1)`? what's the purpose of the `call`-function?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder seems like a form of multiple dispatch to me. In which case the `Actions` signify what to invoke and the arguments to be invoked with. It seems like there should be a better way to produce types for this than just tuples, though.

Comment: @Thomas `call` has a lot of implementation detail that is used regardless of which arguments it takes. Think of it as `fetch`, but basing the promise return type on the URL provided.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in this example, it doesn't really do much. It was just left over from the real code-base and can be removed.

Comment: @SamBautista - Okay, cool. What you're looking for is function overloading, and/or a function overload type. I showed just overloading initially in my answer, but have covered both now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two approaches for you:

1. With your `Call` type as an *overloaded function type*
2. With just an overloaded function.

### With your `Call` type

The type you'd want for `Call` is an overloaded function type. You can define it like this:

```
type Call = {
    (...args: ['add', number, number]): Promise<number>;
    (...args: ['log', string]): Promise<void>;
};
```

Since you need to associate a return type with the parameter list, the `Actions` type doesn't really help.

A function typed with that type will do the inference you've asked for:

```
function doSomething(fn: Call) {
    fn('add', 1, 2)
        .then(value => {
            // Here, TypeScript infers `value` is of type `number`
        });
    fn('log', 'message')
        .then(value => {
            // Here, TypeScript infers `avlue` is of type `void`
        });
}
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=3&ssc=24&pln=3&pc=15#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwVAvFA3gKCjqAKAOiLgCcBzAZwC4oBtAcjgBMn6AaKAOwFcBbAIwgkOPAUIC6AShoAFEgHteASwoQAPKMEkAfAG5suQsXLU69BPLLsoFYCSWcyU2QuWq1AN3lKmezAF99TAAzbk4AY2AleU4oJnkAZUUIYAALBzI8YM4aeCRJDAMcbLxGFmsARg4AJkki3BwCNIhOPA9EbmgUbUKGvtwAegGoAAkhCA4AFXAIBPD7MGAoB2ChCigAA3aETo3l9flgqFBITc0hDfqG-0l9BpLzS2t6XggKCjgyCHo6-sbm1rbTqoHpYP59IajcZTGZzBZLFZrTZwDw7CB7FRQQ7HGabLw+S7gm76fxAA)

If you're going to write functions for that, it may help to have some helper types:

```
type AddParams = ['add', number, number];
type LogParams = ['log', string];
type ActionParams =
    | AddParams
    | LogParams;

type Call = {
    (...args: AddParams): Promise<number>;
    (...args: LogParams): Promise<void>;
};
```

Then for instance:

```
const call: Call = (...args: ActionParams): Promise<any> => {
    // (Dummy implementation)
    if (args[0] === 'add') {
        return Promise.resolve(args[1] + args[2]);
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
};
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnACgQwE7ILYGcoF4oDaA5MgkQDRQB2ArhgEYSqW0NMC6A3AFCiRQAZAPYBzFOmx5CRADaiKULMFQBLKiK69w0GAGNgKoVXGYcublEtQAPrAQnsFq7eFi0pnlv4BhZDJlSAN5OlgAUAHSRaCJYAFx2SO7YAJTxiKhCGCpYEAA8rIyoAHw8VlARUagx8a4OWKlQ6ZnZeQBuQipwJdwAvp66RkpQun4y8b7+UhXh0XGw+obGSfVpGVk5uchUIEV4u8FlAPSH5QAidBggUCoYYDIQGBBUwMgGRskh1wBm5bMEAAzsPC4fAkMjJKAHMpWVAQYA0VBURprFrhWFYIQyVoQUJ-ACMQIA1FA-gAmdjJUpWHqfWHwxHI5o5NEQDFYnGU3r9UahMFwBR4yikj5lcLAAAWT1CrT8NGguH2nyOJwAEkwIJQACraADKulUYGA1yoXyYOAABjKZHLzdccEIfnxoOaCkxzZ8epyRv5eXIRAoiI8sFhkCIIEQRVYxZKqNLZfLFdCrMcoGrYVrdfqVIbjabUBbkK1rRBbdkoA6oE6oJaOnB3WVPTwgA)

### With just an overloaded function

If you just want to write an overloaded function, you don't need the `Call` type (you probably know that):

```
type AddAction = ['add', number, number];
type LogAction = ['log', string];
type Actions =
    | AddAction
    | LogAction;

function call(...args: AddAction): Promise<number>;
function call(...args: LogAction): Promise<void>;
function call(...args: Actions): Promise<any> {
    // ...implementation...
}

call('add', 1, 2)
    .then(value => {
        // Here, TypeScript infers `value` is of type `number`
    });
call('log', 'message')
    .then(value => {
        // Here, TypeScript infers `avlue` is of type `void`
    });
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnGBjYBLA9gOygXigbQHIBDBQgGikwFcBbAIwgCdKaHmBdAbgChRIoAGXQBzZGiy4ChADaiKUAM7AmqTCO59w0cRkyLcPKMagAfWAl1YjJ88LEo9vHgDNqmR5KTEZMgBQAdEHETCKKAFwWiJ6YAJSRAApM6LSoihAAPGyMTAB8vG4eEtjevoHBoRFColZxicmp6RkAbuiocPmu7jFQpf5BASFhkbWK8VBJKWmZxJgguVAA3jbGAPSrUH4AInS0IFCotGAyELQQmMDExbErBy6bQ4r4AAwcuDh4JGSxS7cmUEwIMBqExsJNGhAAoDFOgZM0IH5HvgAIxvADUUCRACYOLFeP8AL63QHA0ETBrTKEQGFwhF4nhEnh9PxfOAKZGULE3f4BYAAC3OfmaPmo0BwC2W-3+6ygAAlmBBKAAVbQAZSQqjAwAOmBczAMAANhTJRQaDgZ0Pd+NADdlmAbbgT6czZPJKIQzopFMQRBBCNyTLyBZghSKxRK-iYZfLAcq1RrUFqdXqmIbiM0TRAzWkoJaoNaoEa2nAHYS8UA)

Comment: I certainly can't think of a better way to do it without overloading the function declaration. I'm not sure TS supports enough logic to say something like "this function takes a tuple as input and returns the last type defined in the tuple" or anything to that effect. Even if it does, I still feel the overloading is clearer as it's more explicit.